# Php , XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xml

This is my first time using ajax which i have being learning from the new Boston website.  but i am getting the following error

> error on line 8 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document

I tried removing white spaces which usually seems to be the fix but that didn't work. Any suggestions would be great.

```html
<?php
 header('Content-Type: text/xml');
 echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';
 echo '<response>';
  $staus;
  $email_in_use = $_GET['email'];
  $query = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM emails WHERE email='".$email_in_use."'");
  if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){

      $staus = false;
      return $status;

  }else{
      // do something
      if (!mysqli_query($con,$query))
      {
          die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
      }else{
       $staus = true;
       return $status;
      }
  }
 echo '</response>';
?>
```

Comment: **Danger**: You are **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that you need to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: The code you have there will put the XML declaration on the first line. Whatever the problem is, we can't tell from looking at the code you've shared with us so far.

Comment: The first thing you should do with debugging this is to look at the output of the script. Open the Developer Tools in your browser. Open the Network tab. Trigger the Ajax request. Examine the response.

Comment: @Quentin thanks for your response What is best practice for defense .  when I go the network it shows noting . i am including this php script at the top of my index page. So i cant access any page. just goes straight to error. The console says                                                                  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cssFloat' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many problems in your script.

First of all, `$staus` is not `$status`: uniform variable names.

But the core problem is that your script will **never** output a corrext XML file:

```
if (!mysqli_query($con,$query))
{
    die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}else{
    $staus = true;
    return $status;
}
```

Either `die()` and `return` stop script execution, so closing `</response>` tag is not printed.

BTW, your error has nothing to do with code in example, unless you have blanks lines or something other before `<?php` declaration.

It's not a good idea output XML in your way, it's better separate execution code and output. Something like this:

```
$email_in_use = $_GET['email'];
(...)
if( !mysqli_query( $con, $query ) )
{ $status = mysqli_error( $con ); }
else
{ $status = 'OK'; }

header( 'Content-Type: text/xml' );
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';
echo '<response>';
echo '<status>'.$status.'</status>';
echo '</response>';
```

End note: to guarantee correct XML, I suggest you to use a XML Parser. With SimpleXML, i.e., you can write in this way:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?><response><status/></response>');
$xml->response->status = $status;
echo $xml->asXML();
```

Comment: Thanks. Ya i would say i have lots of errors, Im just trying to learn still I only started learning php about a week ago. But If I delete every thing inside and just leave the response tagss it still does not work

Comment: First of all, test your script by direct retrieving it in browser, not through ajax. By this way, you can see exact output and isolate the problem. When you are sure that the script is running, call it through ajax.

Comment: Thanks very much for educating me on this, i will implement it now. Can you to me $xml->response->status = $status;
echo $xml->asXML();

Comment: And is the best way to catch this like this:   xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
      xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
      message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;

Comment: I want to get the status varible in the js file

Comment: I'm not a javascript guru, I'm very sorry. I'm work on server side... :( I suggest you to try and — if you have some issue — ask for a new question as javascript tag. I'm very sorry.

Answer (score -1):

`echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';`

This should be your first line for the page. XML expects this to be the first line; no exceptions.

PS. If you remove the `header('Content-Type: text/xml');` 
it will work.

I think what happens here is this line interferes with the opening xml.

Comment: And the code shown will output that as the first line of the request body.